# Question Removed Without Explanation

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This is [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702142/on-mechanism-of-crystal-reports-on-loading-reports) which has been removed without any explanation. Why has it been removed?.

Comment: Take SCREENSHOTS of question! *That* isn't your question...

Comment: @Adel I'm not sure what you're talking about, but that is his question. It's still visible to 10k users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Page Not Found Page it states:

> This question was removed from Stack Overflow for **reasons of moderation**. Please refer to the FAQ for [possible explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) why a question might be removed

It was deleted by Jeff Atwood, and was most likely flagged.

From the Deletion FAQ:

> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.
>
> Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signpoints to other questions may also be removed, as well as questions which have no significant activity over a very long period after being asked.

Comment: `deleted by Jeff Atwood♦ 6 hours ago`

Comment: @Diago, Agreed But one confusion in my mind that it is up voted question by three reputation. Up voted question is useful or not?.

Comment: @mahesh That question has one upvote and one downvote. +5 for the upvote and -2 for down, but it's the total votes of 0 that should indicate how useful it is.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, You may be right but I have seen first it is down voted by -2 up voted and later it seen 0 voted but I think reputation is increased later by +6 Or +7

Comment: It was flagged as low quality, and subsequently edited to add more details (and code) related to the problem... However, it could have used a *lot* more editing for clarity; I realize English is probably not your first language, @mahesh, but you should still do your best to state the problem clearly in the title and present the evidence of your problem straight away: other than knowing Crystal is slow to load your report (sadly, it's slow to load *everyone's* reports, and has been for years), I can't really make head nor tail of what, specifically, you're asking for.

Comment: Still, I'm not sure whether hard deleting it like that was justified. The OP is obviously hanging around, and working to improve it

Comment: @Shog9, I am sorry If some body heart by me but beleive me.It's not my intention, my intention is for improved the quality of crystal reports in later version like vs-2005, It has great feature for maintaining the memory garbage collection which improved connection and loading data between server

Comment: I'm not gonna deny that Crystal looks good on paper, @mahesh, and this isn't the forum for discussing its issues anyway... I'm just saying, a question that consists of "this is slow" doesn't get you very far - you really want to describe how [something specific] is inexplicably slower than [general case], and ask what can be done to avoid the problem. Spending extra time on your phrasing to ensure this is clear to readers will go a long way toward getting your question answered (and not deleted).

Comment: @Pekka: it really could have used *someone else* editing it along the way. IMHO, the core question was too vague - even with edits - to answer, but the grammar didn't help. Though I do *suspect* it wouldn't have been flagged if the original form had been closer to the final form.